# Disable Wordpress subdirectory install to relinquish URL for a page instead

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, subdirectory, multisite

I have inherited a site that has multiple Wordpress subdirectory installs although I have since created pages on the main/root Wordpress install that I would like to replace them with. I dont wish to delete these sub installs just yet but instead relinquish the URL.

So when visiting mainsite.com/test1 I would like it to land on a page on the mainsite which has the permalink /test1 instead of the sub install of the same name. When trying to create a page with the permalink /test1 it automatically changes to /test1-2 as I assume its detecting the sub install.

Hope that makes sense and really appreciate any help you can provide :)

I have ftp access and so I tried to change the wp-config of the sub install with the following in hopes it would disable the site, instead it just displayed pages without any content and only the header and footer...although without any styling.

define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );

Comment: Did you check the database for ‘test-1’? There might already be a post in trash or revision that has this slug, hence Wordpress changes it to ‘test-1-2’. I don’t think this had anything to do with the subfolder of the same name…

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, much appreciated! I did find it weird that only 2 of the 12 pages I created forced me to use an alternative slug ie -2. You was right! I noticed there were two images with the filename being exactly the same as the slug I wanted, so I renamed them and I was able to then change the pages to the desired slug. Now Im just trying to figure out how I can disable these subsites without deleting. I tried renaming the index.php file on one of them to something temp but it just results in 403 error page. Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe rename the folder names?

Comment: Else you will have to mess with the .htaccess file. In this file wordpress checks whether the request url is for a file (-f) or a directory (-d) and only if it is none of those two it does its own magic.

Comment: Thank you so much once again Klaassiek for following up and sharing your expertise! Appreciate you also explaining as to the .htaccess file, I went with your suggestion of renaming the folder names and it work straight away! Amazing! So happy and saved me a lot of trouble/time and so as before, thank so so much, really do appreciate it :)